# Storing MySQL queries in the database (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

How would I store MySQL queries in a table within the MySQL database that they would be executed?

I was thinking of using something like this:

```
id int // unique ID of the query
statement varchar(1000) // actual query
var_list varchar(255) // comma separated list of variables to be used in the query
```

Is there anything else I should use, (or omit) for example the `var_list` - should the variables be hardcoded in the statement itself?

Comment: Why store them? Why not use views?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea, but you may have your reasons. What are you trying to achieve? You haven't given any idea of what kind of queries you will be executing. 1000 characters seems like way too small a buffer and will suffer from truncation.

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish some kind of SQL audit?

Comment: Usually never seen a var_char go over 255, although according to MySQL it can go as high as 65,535, you may want to consider changing the statement column to a `text` type. Why do you want to store queries in a database?

Comment: I thought that it may speed things up? Am I wrong? I haven't looked into views? Will that accomplish something similar? Are stored procedures the same thing? As for Varchar(1000) I just chose a value for demo purposes, I haven't given much thought to how big it should be yet. The statements will be very simple, usually no more than one join.

Comment: -1 because stored proc's, functions and views will cover any scenario storing queries in a table would and do it more efficiently. This method would also be simpler to understand should another dba/developer inherit your code.

Comment: What are the differences between stored procedures and views? From what I have read they seem like they do the same thing, is one better (faster, more efficient, lighter) than the other?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for storing SQL queries in the database.

Comment: There is, for example if you needed to add some kind of advanced reporting functionality to an application whereby users could write SELECT statements. In fact we have a web app which does exactly this.

Comment: Of course there is. If you want to log, for example, which queries you sent to the database BEFORE they are sent to the database